# Problem with opening new tab in a browser

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixi.js

For some interactive graphics we are using canvas in our HTML page. Inside the canvas we have "link-like" controls to link users to external resources.
Because of canvas, we do NOT use `<a href="">` tag, but we are opening new browser tab via JS code, like this:

```
this.pixiLayout.App.renderer.view.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (this.pixiLayout.externalUrl) {
        window.open(this.pixiLayout.externalUrl, '_blank');
    }
});
```

The problem:
Google Analytics(front end) show us much more clicks than actual "page views" analytics from third party resources, up to 10-20 times.
It means that users clicked on the link(and it recorded by GA), but by some reason, link was not opened, or opened but not loaded in a new tab.
I know about ad/pop-ups blockers. It could be a case for some percentage of users. But it is not a case for 90% of users, like we have.

And we could not reproduce this behaviour on any device we own.

Question:
Could it be caused by normal browser policy or restriction that could cause a blocking of new tab like in our case?
Could it be like "new feature" of modern browsers I do not know about yet?

Comment: Happening in all Browsers?

Comment: That does not sound right *"...10 -20 times."* to load a page by repeating the same action, by 90% of clients. No people don't do that. Are you sure you have the google analytics events set up correctly, and not accidentally counting normal interaction as clicks to navigate (open new tab or window (clients option)))

Comment: @Blindman67, it simple means that only 10-5% of all users got web-page loaded in a new tab.

Comment: @ArjanPoortman, no, mainly on mobile. And this type of info gave me a clue to actual cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was in our own code. Event firing of GA(we use custom events) was implemented in the different place of the code than an actual action - `window.open()`. They were supposed to be called on the same user action - user click. But it was not a case, specially for mobile devices. When user tapped on that interactive, link-like control and moved finger up or down(for scrolling), it fired custom event responsible for tracking "the click". But actual "click" event is not fired in this case.

Conclusion: never ever do an actual action in one place and "collect analytics of that action" in another place of the code.